# Aggregate root methods should change the aggregate root state?

Tags: events, aggregate, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Let's imagine that we want to create an application that implements Event sourcing. So we have the following aggregate root:

```kotlin
class Account{

    val balance: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO

    fun apply(event: EntryRegisteredEvent){
        balance -= command.amount
    }

    fun registerNewDebitEntry(command: RegisterNewDebitEntryCommand): EntryRegisteredEvent {
        if(balance < command.amount)
            throw InsufficientBalanceException()

        balance -= command.amount

        return EntryRegisteredEvent.create(...)
    }
}
```

My question is:

Why am I changing the balance state in `registerNewDebitEntry()` function? Shouldn't the method only checks for invariants and create an event? And then leaving only the `apply()` method responsible for changing the state of the aggregate root?

Does this separation make sense?

### Edit 1:

I could apply the event instead of doing the change state logic again:

```kotlin
    fun registerNewDebitEntry(command: RegisterNewDebitEntryCommand): EntryRegisteredEvent {
        if(balance < command.amount)
            throw InsufficientBalanceException()
        
        val event = EntryRegisteredEvent.create(...)
       
        apply(event)

        return event
    }
```

But the question remains. I really need to change the aggregate root at this moment?

### Edit 2

I think the only reason to do this is in cases where you have to apply more than one command in the same process. But in cases where this is not true, I just don't see why we should update AR state

Comment: This code looks a lot more like a "teachable moment" than it does an example of event sourcing done right.  But it's just a pattern, maybe there really are forces in play here that justify the duplication?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason It is just an example there are no forces to justify the duplication. But I saw a lot of examples that change aggregate root state on domain methods and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only answering from a strictly DDD point of view.

One important point of DDD is that the domain entities are unaware of everything else in your application. It should not be dependent on infrastructure, commands, or event sourcing.

The reason is that the only complexity in it should be from the business rules and logic. Making sure that when it does something, it does it right.

That's hard if you start to mix in other things that it has to be responsible for (which also breaks SRP).

A domain entity with no dependencies is also so much easier to test.

In your case, I would have a `Debit` method that takes `amount` argument. I would put the rest of the logic in an application service.

As a direct answer regarding the event. That error check has to be in the command handler method, to prevent faulty events. Where the actual application (as in 'apply to the entity') is doesn't matter. And if you do as suggested above, it will mostly be a one liner so that no logic is duplicated.